# python: generating a histogram

Tags: python

this:

```
 numpy.histogram([1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,5,6,6],bins=numpy.arange(0,7,1))
```

yields:

```
(array([0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

why does it count three 6's? there are only 2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because bins defines the bin **edges** you need to add one more bin

```
numpy.histogram([1,3,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,5,6,6],bins=numpy.arange(0,8,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one 5 and two 6's in the last bin.  Quoting the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) "All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open", so the last bin includes the 2 6's.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's lumping the 5's and 6's together - maybe the last bin is 5 to 6, inclusive?

---

Edit: Looking at the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), I'm guessing that 6 is the rightmost edge, so values between five and six are in that final bin.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to the semantics of the first and last bins being underflow and overflow. Your total bucket count is correct.